# COUNT function in SQL Server with WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to know about `count` function in SQL Server with a `where` clause

Something like...

```
select 
    sum(sales) <-- all sales
    , count(ranking) <-- under 100 ranking
from
    A_chart
```

So I think...

```
select
    sum(sales)
    , count(select * from A_chart where ranking <= 100)
where
    A_chart.
```

`A_chart` data for example

```
ranking sales
1       100
2       50
3       30
4       5
```

Then, I want to know all sales SUM, but ranking under 2.

So, is this right?

```
select 
    sum(all sales), count(ranking < 2) 
where A_chart.
```

Please teach me. Thanks.

Comment: Question is totally obscure.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for

```
select 
 sum(sales) <-- all sales
,count(case when ranking < 100 then 1 end) <-- under 100 ranking
from
A_chart
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear but I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT
  SUM(Sales) as [Sum of Sales],
  COUNT(*) as [Count of Rankings]
FROM
  A_chart
WHERE
  ranking < 2 -- Change this to ranking < 100 for the first part of your question
```